# ASP.net MVC 3 is not creating a SQL table automatically (Following Pluralsight)

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to follow this guide http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/players/PSODPlayer.aspx?author=scott-allen&name=mvc3-building-data-i&mode=live&clip=0&course=aspdotnet-mvc3-intro (Part 3 Code Comes first) but I have followed it like a slave.

Now I have installed a MSDN version so its the Visual Studio Ultimate and not the Web developer express 2010 like he uses and I wonder is that the sole reason for this not working? Because then I will just install that instead.

I get this error when I try to access a site that should use the database

> ```
>     Server Error in '/' Application.
> Value cannot be null.
> Parameter name: key
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the
> ```
>
> execution of the current web request.
>   Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where
>   it originated in the code.
>
> ```
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value
> ```
>
> cannot be null.
>       Parameter name: key
>
> ```
> Source Error:
>
> Line 15:     
> Line 16: 
> Line 17: @foreach (var item in Model)
> Line 18: {
> Line 19:     @item.Title
>
>
> Source File: c:\Users\Mech0z\Documents\Visual
> ```
>
> Studio
>   2010\Projects\FirstWeb\FirstWeb\Views\Gallery\Index.cshtml
>   Line: 17
>
> ```
> Stack Trace:
> ```

My code is:

Connectionstring:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices"
         connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="GalleryDb"
         connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;initial catalog=GalleryDb"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Picture model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace FirstWeb.Models
{
    public class Picture
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Path { get; set; }
        public List<Comment> Comments { get; set;}
        public int ConcertYear { get; set; }
        public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
        public string UploadBy { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My controller

```
namespace FirstWeb.Controllers
{
    public class GalleryController : Controller
    {
        GalleryDb _db = new GalleryDb();
        //
        // GET: /Gallery/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var model = _db.Pictures;
            return View(model);
        }
```

And my galleryDB

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace FirstWeb.Models
{
    public class GalleryDb : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Picture> Pictures { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Comment> Comments { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Picture> GetPictures()
        {
            return Pictures;
        }

        public void AddPicture(Picture model)
        {
            Pictures.Add(new Picture
            {
                Title = model.Title,
                Path = model.Path,
                Comments = new List<Comment>(),
                ConcertYear = model.ConcertYear
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I have a few extra methods thats not workign whicih is just something from when I used temp data without SQL

But as said I cant connect to the db the way he does (Typing .\sqlexpress and typing GalleryDb as name) and it gives me an error

But the database must be running as I can create a user and login at any point

Comment: Are you able to connect to the database in the Visual Studio Server Explorer?  What connection string do you have configured in web.config?  Can you paste your whole <connectionStrings> section of your web.config file?

Comment: Kyle Trauberman http://pastebin.com/gJKfz6s7

Comment: But no I cant connect when I try .\sqlexpress and GalleryDb

Comment: Does the GalleryDb database exist?  You might need to create the database yourself before CodeFirst will generate the tables.

Comment: When I cant connect to it I suppose it dont exist? I only did the "add connection" then type .\sqlexpress and then the name GalleryDb I cant find any way to look at the databases on my computer through sql server 2008?

Comment: In VS Server Explorer add connection dialog, if you enter`.\sqlexpress` for the server, you should be able to expand the database name dropdown to view a list of the databases available to you on that SQL instance.

Comment: Can it be that I need something like System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<GalleryDb>());

            System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer<GalleryDb>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<GalleryDb>());

Comment: Possibly, but you said that you can't connect to it via the server explorer, which means you are having problems connecting to the database engine itself, in which case that code won't do you any good.

Comment: When I installed webdeveloper express on my laptop (after a format) it worked instantly :S so lame the VS Ultimate wont do that, so guess I will remove that and install the express version for now on my desktop :/

Comment: OMG its the public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; } if that is in there it cant work. Jesus that only took me a 24 hours to figure out and randomly I tried removing that part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the Data Entity do not like this property

`public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }`

So after removing that from my model it worked fine